# $http call, error handling in angular js not working

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, angular-fullstack

```
function registrationSave(data){
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'registration/save',
                data: data
            }).then(function(response){
                 console.log("@@@1 "+JSON.stringify(response));
            },function(error){
                  console.log("@@@2"+JSON.stringify(error));
                  return error.data;
            }).catch(function (data) {
                // Handle error here
            });
    };
```

THis is the server response for the service in case of error

//Server response

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Failled with registration Id 1,341.",
    "result": "False"
}
```

In case of 400 error client code response is undefined ? It never going to error section in the client code.

Why is it so ?

This is the interceptor used

```
   /**
         * To handle error response.
         */
        function responseError(error) {
              if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) {
                  if(error.data != null && error.data.code === 401 ){ //access denied error
                      toaster.error( 'Access denied', 'User does not have privilege');
                  }
              }

        }
```

In case of 400, Can I return back to the method here ?

Comment: you have not passed proper data, may be you missed id or you passed some wrong data. so that it is showing 400 bad request

Comment: Bad request I'm sending from server side, but client is receiving as undefined

Comment: Do you have any interceptors in your application?

Comment: I think u r not sending the error as an error. Rather you are just sending JSON response. The problem is not with AngularJS, its the server-side code that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Raghu Venmarathoor Yes Its going to Interceptor.

Comment: else if(error.status === 400){
               throw error;
              }, added this code in interceptor and solved.

Comment: @user630209 I didn't understand why you had to throw an error. The mistake in my case was when I wrote an interceptor which didn't return a promise when handling `responseError`

Comment: Then how can I return the control back to calling method from interceptor ?

Answer (score 1):

If the HTTP status code is between 200 and 299 the success function of [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) is called, otherwise the error function is called.  It appears that the HTTP status code returned from the server is a 200, while the `code` field in the message body is 400.  In the success function there is no `return` so undefined is what you see.  You can verify if this is happening if you observe @@@1 in the browser console.  In the browser's developer tools network tab you can also see the HTTP status code and verify if it is between 200 and 299.

Comment: Status Code:400 , it is 400. DO I need to change this ?

Comment: When the error will be called, which status code range ?

Comment: In the browser's console, do you see @@@1?  If you add `console.log('@@@3')` into the `catch` function, you should see either @@@1, @@@2, or @@@3.

Comment: @@@1 undefined, I can see  this. It should go to error section with the value why it give as @@@1 undefined, that was my question.

Comment: My answer is to your question about why it doesn't go to the error section.

Comment: I'd check what is happening in the interceptor for why it gives an undefined response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129868/discussion-between-user630209-and-logan-rakai).